# How to come back to the MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So in my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page1 Scene1 = new Page1();
            MainFrame.Navigate(Scene1);
        }
```

And in my Page1.xaml.cs I have:

```
private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
```

And when i use the Button_Click the Page1 opens but with the contetn of the main window on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

If MainWindow.Xaml consist in any folder then need to provide the root path.
For Ex: "Views/MainWindow.xaml"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(App.Current.MainWindow.Content);
    }
```